# How do I get nicer diagnostic information from boost::exception?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm throwing a `boost::exception` using

```
BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(trace_collector_error_t()
    << boost::errinfo_api_function("ioctl")
    << boost::errinfo_errno(errno)
    << errinfo_trace_params_t(trace_params));
```

and after

```
std::cerr << boost::diagnostic_information(e) << std::endl;
```

I get

```
: Throw in function trace_config_t set_up_trace(size_t, size_t)
Dynamic exception type: N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implI23trace_collector_error_tEE
std::exception::what: std::exception
[P23errinfo_trace_params_t_] = [ type: 14trace_params_t, size: 16, dump: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
22, "Invalid argument"[PN5boost21errinfo_api_function_E] = ioctl
```

I have two questions:

- How do I get nicer type names?
- How do I get the errinfo_errno to be printed properly?

I'm using GCC 4.6 and Boost 1.55.0.

Comment: What platform is this on?  I seem to recall it working a bit nicer for me on Fedora Linux with the same GCC and a bit older Boost.

Comment: Well, likely you have an older/incompatible GCC. I've checked your example and got much better results.

Comment: Weird typenames are simply mangled C++ names, you can demangle them manually. See more at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html But as I said below my Boost-1.53/GCC-4.7.2 combination does it "automagically"

Comment: @user3159253 (Offtopic: English is not my first language. Why not use the word "automatically", which seems to describe what you are trying to say?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those struggling: switching to Boost version 1.53 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is not a answer, but I can't put it into comments w/o breaking formatting completely. So here it is.

I've got the following results with GCC-4.7.2 and Boost-1.53. *Update: just checked GCC-4.8.1/Boost-1.53 in Ubuntu 13.10, it works the same way as the code below*

```
#include <errno.h>

#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct trace_collector_error: virtual std::exception, virtual boost::exception {};

typedef boost::error_info<struct trace_tag_t, int> trace_info;

namespace a {
class A {
public:
        A() { clog << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl; }
        void f() {
                clog << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
                BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(trace_collector_error()
                        << boost::errinfo_api_function("ioctl")
                        << boost::errinfo_errno(errno)
                        << trace_info(1)
                );
        }
};
}

int main(void) {
        a::A a;
        try {
                a.f();
        } catch (const trace_collector_error& e) {
                std::cerr << boost::diagnostic_information(e) << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
alex@galene tmp/c++/tests $ build/boost_exception_test 
a::A::A()
void a::A::f()
/home/alex/tmp/c++/tests/boost_exception_test.cpp(23): Throw in function void a::A::f()
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl
std::exception::what: std::exception
[trace_tag_t*] = 1
[boost::errinfo_errno_*] = 0, "Success"
[boost::errinfo_api_function_*] = ioctl
```

This is my compiler version/build:

```
alex@galene tmp/c++/tests $ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=i586-alt-linux-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/i586-alt-linux/4.7.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i586-alt-linux
Configured with: ../configure --host=i586-alt-linux --build=i586-alt-linux --target=i586-alt-linux --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var/lib --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --disable-dependency-tracking --without-included-gettext --enable-shared --enable-bootstrap --program-suffix=-4.7 --with-slibdir=/lib --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.altlinux.org --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --without-included-gettext --enable-multilib --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,java,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --with-native-libdir=/usr/lib/gcj-4.7 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.7-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --disable-libjava-multilib --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 20121109 (ALT Linux 4.7.2-alt7) (GCC) 
alex@galene tmp/c++/tests $
```